# Flyway - auto increment id not working with test data in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, crud, flyway

Before I added Flyway to my project, I could run POST request and the new user was created successfully with ID = 1, next one ID = 2 etc.

Then I added Flyway to create tables and insert some test data by V1_init.sql:

```
create table "user"(
  id int8 not null,
  username varchar(255),
);
insert into "user" values (1, 'user1');
insert into "user" values (2, 'user2');
insert into "user" values (3, 'user3');
```

Table is created. Users are inserted.

Trying to run POST request -> error 500

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "organisation_pkey" Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

So my app should add new user with ID=4 but it looks like it can't recognize that there are 3 users already added.

I'm using GenericEntity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericEntity<ID extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected ID id;
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-app
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I tried to use all strategies @GeneratedValue, changing spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto, adding users in init.sql without id (not working)

but still no positive effects. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have only a half understanding of what you're doing...

> I tried to use all strategies @GeneratedValue

You don't need to randomly try strategies, you need to pick the one that matches your current database design.

> changing spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto

This is dangerous and you should set it to "none", given that you are using flyway.

> adding users in init.sql without id (not working)

This will only work if postgresql is set up to automatically generate ids (which is easiest through a sequence).
From your code, it does not look like that is the case.

> what could be wrong?

JPA's `@GeneratedValue` is capable of ensuring that values are generated when it is responsible for creating rows (that means when you pass `EntityManager#persist`). It does not and can not know about your flyway scripts where you bypass JPA to insert rows manually.

Furthermore, let's look at `@GeneratedValue`'s `strategy` property. The strategy you choose will influence *how* JPA generates IDs. There are only a few options: `TABLE`, `SEQUENCE`, `IDENTITY` and `AUTO`. Since you did not explicitly specify a strategy, you are currently using the default, which is `AUTO`. This is not recommended because it is not explicit, and now it's hard to say what your code is doing.

Under the `TABLE` and `SEQUENCE` strategies, JPA will do an interaction with the database in order to generate an ID value. In those cases, JPA is responsible for generating the value, though it will rely on the database to do so. Unsurprisingly, the former will use a table (this is rare, btw, but also the only strategy that is guaranteed to work on all RDBMS) and the latter will use a sequence (far more common and supported by practically every commercially relevant RDBMS).
With `IDENTITY`, JPA will not attempt to generate a key at all, because this strategy assumes that the DB will generate an ID value on its own. The responsibility is thus delegated to the database entirely. This is great for databases that have their own auto-increment mechanism.

Postgres does not really have an auto-increment system but it has some nice syntactic sugar that nearly makes it work like it: the [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) "datatype". If you specify the datatype of a column as "serial", it will in fact be created with datatype int, but postgresql will also create a sequence and tie the default value of the ID column to the sequence's next value generator.

In your case, JPA is most likely using either SEQUENCE or TABLE. Since your DDL setting is set to "update", Hibernate will have generated a table or sequence behind your back. You should check your database with something like pgAdmin to verify which it is, but I'd put my money on a sequence (so I'm assuming it's using the SEQUENCE strategy).
Because you haven't specified a `@SequenceGenerator`, a default will be used which, AFAIK, will start from 1.

Then when JPA tries to insert a new row, it will call that sequence to generate an ID value. It will get the next value of the sequence, which will be 1. **This will conflict with the IDs you manually entered in flyway.**

My recommended solution would be to:

- redefine your postgresql data type from int8 to "serial" (which is actually int + a sequence + sets up default value linking the ID column to the sequence so that postgres will automatically generate an ID if you don't explicitly specify one - careful, also don't specify `null`, just don't specify the ID column in the insert statement at all!)
- explicitly set the generator strategy to `IDENTITY` on the JPA side
- update your flyway scripts to insert users without explicit ID value (this will ensure that the test data advance the sequence, so that when JPA uses that same sequence later, it will not generate a conflicting ID)

I'd say there are alternative solutions, but other than using the `TABLE` strategy or generating keys in memory (both things which you should avoid), there isn't really a viable alternative because it will boil down to using a sequence anyway. I suppose it's possible to manually specify the sequence, forego the default value on the id field, call the sequence manually in your insert statements, and map the sequence explicitly in JPA... but I don't see why you'd make things hard on yourself.